# IntelliTrace Collector for Visual Studio Error

Tags: iis-7, intellitrace

I've installed the IntelliTrace Collector for Visual Studio (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30665).

I've setup the logging directory and gave the app pool full permission to the directory.

I've loaded the Powershell DLL "Import-Module .\Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.PowerShell.dll" and successfully issued the Start-IntelliTraceCollection command.

I see the log file gets created at that point.

However, when I issue the Stop-IntelliTraceCollection powershell command I get an error that says:

"Stop-IntelliTraceCollection : Application pool "Process ID c215cecb-1b1d-4c88-a20c34040e6ac84a" must be recycled with the "Load User Profile" option set.
At line:1 char:28

- Stop-IntelliTraceCollection <<<<  devapppool

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Stop-IntelliTraceCollection], LoadUserProfileException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.WebInstrument.LoadUserProfileException,Microsoft.Visua
    lStudio.IntelliTrace.PowerShell.StopIntelliTraceCollectionCommand"

I've verified that Load User Profile is set to true on the application pool.

We are running IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run your PowerShell command window with Administrative permissions? This error doesn't necessarily mean that you need to change your settings. It can show up for several reasons. Most likely, the IIS process that you were monitoring was forcibly quit outside of PowerShell before you called the Stop-IntelliTraceCollection command, or your PowerShell doesn't have permissions to tell IIS to restart. All this error is saying is that the given process could not be recycled, and that you may have to restart it manually with the "Load User Profile" option set.

Have you checked the IntelliTrace file? Are you able to open it in Visual Studio?